# war conflict in maven

Tags: maven, guava, maven-jar-plugin

mybatis-generator-maven-plugin has  dependencies of sisu-guava(maven-plugin-api) and google-collect(plexus-container-default). Both of them has com.google.common.collect.Ordering class, but 
the one in google-collect does not have the "reverse" function. How can I make sure the reverse function in sisu-guava is called.

Also， why the war package has maven related jars like "maven-plugin-api-3.0.4.jar" 、"maven-model-3.0.4.jar". I don't think they are useful for tomcat .

[image: maven dependency]

Comment: It sounds like you have a plugin as a dependency defined in your pom which is simply wrong. If you need to use a plugin use it as plugin and **NOT** as dependency.

Comment: @khmarbaise  resolve it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a plugin as a dependency defined in your pom which is simply wrong. If you need to use a plugin use it as plugin and NOT as dependency.